# Sharepoint Server 2007 - Change Authentication to AD

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, active-directory, admin

I set up a test Sharepoint 2007 Server before I set up a test AD Server to add it to.  Based on what I read I did this backwards and if I would have set it up the other way around Sharepoint would use AD by default.

Is there a way I can change the configuration so this Sharepoint server will authenticate against the domain?

I did some searches in the configuration as well as SO and Google and couldn't come up with anything obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to move your server into the new AD domain. Optionally you can change all the accounts that are used by SharePoint services to domain accounts, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934838. SharePoint will continue to work with local accounts though.

For any user rights assignment you did using local server accounts you can run the command: [stsadm -o migrateuser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262141.aspx) to migrate user accounts from local\user to domain\user.